# How to set default values for RadioGroupFieldEditor

Tags: java, swt

I have a RadioGroupFieldEditor field in my class. I want to set the defualt values. Is it possible.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you can load the default value from the preference store with `doLoadDefault()`. You can set the preference store with `setPreferenceStore()` - see [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fpreference%2FRadioGroupFieldEditor.html)